# How to use torchvision.io.read_image with image as variable, not stored file?

Tags: python, torch, torchvision

`torchvision.io.read_image` uses as an input file stored in `path` argument. How can I achieve the same output if the image is stored as a variable? Of course, I can just save the image as a file and then read from it but it is additional time. Is there a way to get the same result as `torchvision.io.read_image` with input as a variable, not path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the images in memory are PIL images, you can use a transform function to convert it to a tensor in the right format (achieving the same effect as `torchvision.io.read_image` without the need of reading something from the disk).

```py
import PIL
import torchvision.transforms.functional as transform

# Reads a file using pillow
PIL_image = PIL.Image.open(image_path)

# The image can be converted to tensor using
tensor_image = transform.to_tensor(PIL_image)

# The tensor can be converted back to PIL using
new_PIL_image = transform.to_pil_image(tensor_image)
```